# How do I import an 11g dump into Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c

We use to run this command to import a DB in 11g:

```
impdp system directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=ourdb.dmp full=n
password: ourpassword
```

Now I am trying to run this in 12c:

```
impdp system/Oracle_1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=ourdb.dmp nologfile=Y
```

But it is saying the User doesn't exist so everything is failing.
In 11g it would just create the USER from the schema it was importing.
What's going on in 12c?

I read you have to make sure you are connected to the pdb.
So if I connect to the pdb:

```
sqlplus sys/Oracle_1 as sysdba;
```

I am now at an SQL Prompt.
Now if I run:

```
impdp system/Oracle_1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=ourdb.dmp nologfile=Y
```

It says, this is not an sqlplus command.  You have to run it from a regular command line.
So if I go back to a regular command line I am not connected as I am no in SQLPus.  I don't get this.

Can anyone tell me the steps here?
I can't find a good doc to guide me through this.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the connect string supplied to `impdp`. In a regular DB like Oracle 11g the connect string is straight forward.

For example:

```
impdp system/manager ...
```

But in case of Oracle 12c, which is a [multi-tenant database](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1). We need to supply the container in the connect string.

For example:

```
impdp system/manager@pdb1 ...
```

Also, note that `impdp` is an external Oracle tool. Its not a SQL*Plus command.

Comment: Thank you so much for that.  I knew it was something like that.  Couldn't nail down that syntax though.  I'm one step further."
Now it I have a few more errors working through.
1) Invalid arguent value:
This is the command:
impdp system/Oracle_1@pdborcl directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=ourdb.dmp nologfile=Y
2) bad dump file specification.
3) directory name DATA_PUMP_DIR is invalid.
I thought the default dump dir on this install was:
C:\ade\aime_v\oracle\admin\seeddata\dpdump,
Although I would rather it be:
C:\app\OracleHomeUser1\admin\orcl\dpdump.
Not sure why it seems to be set to the former.